Unknown childrens animated tv show
Me and my friend both remember a kids show, but we can't seem to figure out if we both dreamt it or if it was in fact real. What I can remember from the show:
There were two human children (I think) and they were sent under the sea to help some seahorses. They were huge and in all different colours, in the similar style as the seahorse apparing in Ariel. They had necklaces with jeweles on them. They could talk and interact with the kids, and one pink seahorse was very protective and motherly over the kids.
We were so young when we saw it so our memory of it isn't too detailed. One more thing, we saw it on TV in the late 90's or early 2000's. It was shown in Norway and dubbed to Norwegian. If that can help. I've spent hours looking for it, and this might be my last hope.... 

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

There was not only a movie, but also a TV-Series of Ariel the mermaid including severeal Seahorses and some follow up movies, but i guess you dont mean that?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Mermaid_%28TV_series%29

Are you 100% sure they were seahorses?

Yes i am, but if you have a suggestion that would state otherwise, then please do share.

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Another option could be a japanese tv-series like Ariel in the early 90s called Adventures of the Little Mermaid, including riding sea horses (at 4:40):




It's called Happy Ness (1995) and I was looking for the same thing with the same vague memories and literally went through everything I could find and do within my power to find it. It took 4 hours but that nagging feeling I've had is gone because it was my favorite show and all I had was the last line of the TV show stuck in my head!




Maybe it is Snorks, in this animated show they used to ride on seahorses.




No, it wasnt that, but thanks for trying tho ☺️

Could this be Help! I'm a Fish?
Its a child movie from 2000, including Sahsa the seahorse. Did not see it myself, only found it by research, and what i read about it does not really match your description, but maybe you mean the scene here:




No the children were riding on the seahorses. So It's not that one.

Could it have been My Little Pony - Fireflies Adventure?
It does not fully match your description, but perhaps this sparks some recognition: Song from the movie.
It's really a wild shot, but with vague memories being involved, it may be a random hit.

I have a very visual memory of the show, so when i see it i will know. But it wasn't my little pony, but i do appreciate the try! Thank you so much!
